# Cloud 9 and Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide

I'm running grunt.js on Cloud9.  Most everything is working correctly, except when I try to set this option:

```
'watch: {
    options: {livereload:true},'
```

If I add that, the terminal states:  'Fatal error: listen EACCES'

I'm guessing I need to use the sudo command to run that and since c9 doesn't let you run sudo, the command fails.

But why is livereload a feature that requires permission?  And is there any way around it?